# Table catalog_category_product_index_store0 doesn't exist on renaming store

Tags: magento2, database, not-found

In my magento 2 store we have a store that was disabled for future use, now we want to use it but decided to renamed it to something else.

In Admin panel under Stores > Al stores I renamed the Website , Store and Store view (inside of Store view I enabled it) and when trying to access it through the browser I am getting that a specific table that doest not exist :

catalog_category_product_index_store0

I checked my databases and this table does not exist, I have tried to reindex but it is still not working, not sure what to do, i don't really want to touch databases.

I also updated the core_config_data base_url for http and https and added the right apache configuration so it is not that.I am really lost.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just figure out that I did not set up the apache configuration for this, something like this but with your own parameters,this did the trick :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento2
    ServerName www.magento2.local
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "nameofshop"
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "website"
    <Directory /var/www/html/magento2/pub >
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```